PostgreSQL Query Error: Missing FROM-clause entry for table 'a'
I am working on a Nest.js application using PostgreSQL(postgres.js javascript framework), and I have two tables: addresses and users. I am trying to join these tables and filter the results based on an ID. However, I keep encountering the following error:
missing FROM-clause entry for table "a"

Here is the SQL query I am using:
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.address, 
    a.landmark, 
    a.city, 
    a.state, 
    a.country, 
    a.zipcode, 
    json_build_object(
        'id', u.id, 
        'first_name', u.first_name, 
        'last_name', u.last_name, 
        'email', u.email, 
        'contact_number', u.contact_number, 
        'image', u.image
    ) AS user 
FROM 
    addresses a 
INNER JOIN 
    users u 
ON 
    a.user_id = u.id
WHERE 
    a.id = 102

Here are the table definitions for reference:
-- Table: addresses
CREATE TABLE addresses (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    landmark VARCHAR(255),
    city VARCHAR(100),
    state VARCHAR(100),
    country VARCHAR(100),
    zipcode VARCHAR(20),
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
);

-- Table: users
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(100),
    last_name VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    contact_number VARCHAR(20),
    image VARCHAR(255)
);

I have verified that the table names and columns are correct. Despite this, I still encounter the error.
Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

your query seems correct, can you share your table structure and data for us to test at our end

have you tried this directly against the postgres db (ie not via the js framework?) . if it works there it may something else within your js code environment

@hassaanmustafa Thanks for your response, I have edited the question and added the table structure. The query is simple and yet I am still confused why this is happening.

@ticktalk Thanks for your response. It's working fine in the postgres db but not on the nest.js environment. I am using postgres.js package to interact with the postgres database.

You application is clearly making a different query, but we don't know what query and you haven't shared any code.

@angkushsahu can you share the code as well where your query is being executed.
